# how to replot saved figures in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB script in which I saved multiples figures, now I would like to read them again with MATLAB, I tried the function `hgload` and also `imread` but it didn't help. any idea this could be done  ?

**UPDATE**

```
fig = hgload('FRAME.fig');
plot(fig);
```

Comment: How have you saved them? `.fig`? `.png`? `.eps`?

Comment: I've saved them as .fig files !

Comment: `hgload`works always for me. What is the error message you got?

Comment: I don'T get an error message I just get a empty plot

Comment: Just try `hgload FRAME.fig`

Comment: sorry for being that stupid it works now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use: `hgload FRAME.fig`

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
open FRAME.fig
```

it will open the figure as if it was plotted